If $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, -) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-, a)$, must $\mathcal{C}$ be a groupoid?
Let $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a covariant functor and $G: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a contravariant functor. A mixed natural transformation $\eta: F \to G$ is a collection of maps $\eta_c: F(c) \to G(c)$, $c \in \mathcal{C}$ such that for each morphism $f: c \to d$, the following diagram commutes:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(c) @>\eta_c>> G(c) \\
@VF(f)VV @AAG(f)A \\
F(d) @>\eta_d>> G(d) \\
\end{CD}
$$
This means that $\eta_c = G(f) \circ \eta_d \circ F(f)$.
It is also clear how to define a mixed natural transformation if we swap the roles of the covariant functor and the contravariant functor, and this gives us a notion of mixed natural isomorphism.

As an example, consider the covariant and contravariant $\operatorname{Hom}$ functors. I can prove the following:
Example 1. If $\mathcal{C}$ has a zero object (i.e. an object which is both an initial and a terminal object), then there is a unique mixed natural transformation
$$
\eta: \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, -) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-, b)
$$
and it is constantly zero.
Proof. Take any $c$ and consider the zero object $0$. Since $0$ is a terminal object, there is a unique map $0: c \to 0$. we obtain the following commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, c) @>\eta_c>> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(c, b) \\
@V[0 \circ -]VV @AA[- \circ 0]A \\
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, 0) @>\eta_0>> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(0, b) \\
\end{CD}
$$
Hence we have $\eta_c(g) = \eta_0(0 \circ g) \circ 0$. But this is a map factoring through $0$, and there is only one such map.
Example 2. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid (i.e. all morphisms are invertible), then
$$
\eta: \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, -) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-, a), \\
\eta_b: \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, b) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(b, a), \\
\eta_b(f) = f^{-1}
$$
is a mixed natural isomorphism.
Proof. We need to show that for any $f: c \to d$, the following diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, c) @>\eta_c>> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(c, a) \\
@V[f \circ -]VV @AA[- \circ f]A \\
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a,d) @>\eta_d>> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(d, a) \\
\end{CD}
$$
Indeed, we have $\eta_c(g) = g^{-1}$ and
$$
\eta_d(f \circ g) \circ f = (f \circ g)^{-1} \circ f = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f = g^{-1}
$$
Hence $\eta_c(g) = \eta_d(f \circ g) \circ f$, so $\eta_c = [- \circ f] \circ \eta_d \circ [f \circ -]$.
It is clear that we can also construct an inverse mixed natural transformation for $\eta$, showing that $\eta$ is in fact a mixed natural isomorphism.

Having played around with these examples quite a bit, I came to the following conjecture:

If $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(a, -) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-, a)$ for all $a$, then $\mathcal{C}$ must be a groupoid.

Question: Is this conjecture true?

Maybe we can through such an iso give an inverse for any f:a—>b since we would have some correspondance with some g:b—> a. Do you require C to be locally small ?

If you only require this for a single $a$, then we can take $a$ to be a zero object in $\mathcal{C}$ to get such an isomorphism.

@DanielApol Oh, right! I have updated the question.

@julio_es_sui_glace I'm willing to make the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small, otherwise my $\operatorname{Hom}$ functor doesn't even land in $\mathsf{Set}$. Your approach seems promising.

I’ll think about it tomorrow if I can but maybe someone will have answered already

The assumption if the category is locally small or not doesn't make a difference. In the general case we have hom-collections instead of hom-sets, and collections behave just like sets (I work in ZFC + universes).

Your conjecture is correct, even a stronger form.
Let $F$ be a covariant functor, $G$ be a contravariant functor and let $\eta : F \to G$ be a mixed natural transformation that is objectwise surjective. For every $u \in G(Y)$ then there is a $v \in F(Y)$ with $\eta_Y(v) = u$. Applying mixed naturality to any morphism $f : Y \to Z$ shows
$$u=\eta_Y(v) = G(f)(\eta_Z(F(f)(v)).$$
In particular, $u \in G(Y)$ lies in the image of $G(f) : G(Z) \to G(Y)$ for any $f : Y \to Z$. This is a quite strong property. Such contravariant functors are called flasque in the special case of presheaves on a space.
I claim that all $\hom(-,X)$ are flasque iff the category is a groupoid. The one direction is clear.
Now assume that every $\hom(-,X)$ is flasque. This means that every morphism $Y \to X$ lifts along any morphism $Y \to Z$ to a morphism $Z \to X$. In particular, the identity $X \to X$ lifts along any morphism $X \to Z$ to a morphism $Z \to X$. This means, every morphism $X \to Z$ is a split monomorphism. But we have this for all objects, so actually $Z \to X$ is a monomorphism as well, and then it must be the inverse of $X \to Z$.

"But we have this for all objects, so actually $Z \to X$ is a monomorphism as well, and then it must be the inverse of $X \to Z$." I can't quite follow. Take $f: X \to Z$ and $g: Z \to X$ with $gf = \operatorname{id}$. Now if we assume that $g$ already has an inverse $g^{-1}$, then we have $gf = \operatorname{id}$ and $g g^{-1} = \operatorname{id}$, so since $g$ is a monomorphism we deduce that $g^{-1} = f$ (this is just the proof of uniqueness of inverses). But in our case we can't assume that $g$ already has an inverse, so how does that work?

g is a split epi and a mono, hence an iso.
